# Parse a full datetime string to DateTime type

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to Parse this string "Wed Jun 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)" into a DateTime! can this be done in .NET Framework?

[EDIT]

I think the problem is how to express this (GTB Daylight Time)...

Thank you.

Comment: are you passing the string to db ??

Comment: No i'm passing this string via JavaScript from a DevExpress DateEdit control, startDateEdit.GetValue().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have valid reasons why you're extracting the date on the client via GetValue() before passing it to the server (instead of accessing the server-side dateEdit.Date property)....:

GetValue() (or GetDate() for that matter) return a JavaScript date object. You can format it using JavaScript's built-in getXXX() methods specified [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). before passing it to a server, such as:

```
dt.GetValue().getMonth() + '/' + dt.GetValue().getDate() + '/' + dt.GetValue().getFullYear()
```

=> returns '5/8/2011', which you can parse using .NET's DateTime.Parse/ParseExact methods.

But really, you should double-check whether extracting the date on the client (instead of using the server-side properties) is the best way to go.

Comment: This was what i actually implemented to solve the problem....so its marked as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx).

Comment: I think you can do this on your own, don't you? I would also need to look it up. Don't be so lazy... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like:

```
"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

Comment: Well, yes. I deleted the "tt" specifier. But I#m not quite sure if DateTime will handle "GMT+0300" using the "zzz" specifier

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more information in the string than DateTime can handle.  Have you considered using DateTimeOffset.Parse.
Once you have parsed the DateTimeOffset, refer to this article to convert it to DateTime (if you need to)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546101.aspx